# How to learn modern music with guitar

Tags: guitar, strumming

I am always wondering how to learn modern music like strumming etc. I've been playing classical guitar but never get in touch with modern music like strumming. I understand since I have classical guitar as my base skill to learn the modern music should be difficult.

What do I need to start with?

Comment: A steel string guitar (electric or acoustic) and a pick are pretty important ingredients for learning to strum.

Comment: What about the techniques apart from just strumming, where can i learn those technique

Comment: What do you need to start with? A teacher is always a good start. Perhaps the one you use for classical would put you on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical guitar is a notoriously difficult instrument; if you have a good grounding in that, (most) pop will (probably) be very easy. If you have an electric or steel string acoustic, use that (not just for the sound but the strings of either require less pressure and less precision to get a note out of, and the necks are more manageable in size for some chords).

But really, there is no trick or technique to it - get a plectrum, watch a few videos of people playing (of professionals, not video tutorials on YouTube which are very often crap), and imitate the sound that they make.

If you have any knowledge at all of classical theory, you'll have a much better understanding of functional harmony than most people who start playing pop.

Answer (score 5):

You can start to practice with your existing guitar, but as mentioned you probably will need to get a steel strung guitar in order to learn the different technique requirements.

If you look at the questions we have tagged with [guitar](/questions/tagged/guitar) and [electric-guitar](/questions/tagged/electric-guitar) you will see many on strumming, picking, rhythm, up- and down-strokes etc.

If you already play classical guitar then playing chords is not going to be an issue for you, but you may wish to read the questions on chord sequences to understand modern and popular theory.